# Ios custom tableView : No visible @interface for 'XYZCustomCell' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:'

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to complete this tutorial : http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells

I'm stuck at the end with this function :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    XYZCustomCell *cell = (XYZCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[XYZCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    XYZTextFieldFormElement *item = [self.formItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.labelField.text = item.label;
    cell.valueField.delegate = self;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

At this line : **cell = [[XYZCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];** I have the error written in the subject's title.

Moreover, labelField and valueField aren't found. Here is XYZCustomCell.m and .h :

```
//  XYZCustomCell.m
#import "XYZCustomCell.h"

@implementation XYZCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end

//  XYZCustomCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *valueField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *labelField;

@end
```

I'm pretty sure to have followed correctly the tutorial's steps. Do you know where the error could come from ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you would get that error, but the tutorial is adding useless code. When you register the nib, like the author does in the tutorial, the cell will never be nil, so that if(cell == nil) clause is entirely unnecessary. If all you need are some IBOutlets for your cell, then you don't need any code at all in the .m file either.

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. Sometimes it gets confused.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. When I restart xcode, the problem is still the same, but when I replace XYZCustomCell by UITableViewCell, it compiles. I don't understand, XYZCustomCell inherits from UITableViewCell and I imported it in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I did a refactoring to remove all the XYZ prefixes before the classes and it works...

Comment: How does that help? Then you lose your two text fields.